# Lazy-seq generator using range in clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

say I want to create a lazy sequence of all numbers from 1 to `m` which their greatest common divisor with `m` is equal to `1`:

```
(def m 38941629971148227236N)
(def possible-e
  (lazy-seq (filter #(= 1 (gcd % m)) (range 1 m) ))
  )
```

then I can `take` a sequence like

```
(take 10 possible-e)
=> (1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19)
```

but when I try to do the same thing in a different way, things don't work. I think it's calculating all the numbers since it takes like forever to print anything:

```
(def possible-e
  (lazy-seq (filter #(= 1 (gcd % m)) (reverse (range 1 m)) ))
  )
```

why it's not working the same way? what's the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
(reverse (range 1 m))
```

Before your code can move to `filter` it has to compute complete `range`. You can use `range` with negative step instead:

```
(def possible-e
  (lazy-seq (filter #(= 1 (gcd % m)) (range (dec m) 0 -1)))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Extended comment:*

- `filter` is lazy, so `lazy-seq` is redundant in both cases.
- Don't `(def m ...)`. Make `possible-e` a function with argument `m`.

So we get

```
(defn possible-e [m]
  (filter #(= 1 (gcd % m)) (range 1 m)))

(def m 38941629971148227236N)
```

and

```
(defn possible-e [m]
  (filter #(= 1 (gcd % m)) (reverse (range 1 m))))
```